# Check if a switch statement is true

Tags: php, switch-statement

I wanted to check if my switch statement is true and if it is, I want to do something with it. e.g.

```
$a = trim($_POST['code']);

    switch ($a) {
    case "123";
        break;
    case "467";
        break;
    default : "incorrect";
    }
```

I then want to do an if statement like this

```
if(switch == true) {
    $a = trim($_POST['code']);
}
else {
$Error ="incorrect code";
$hasError = true;
}
```

*if(switch == true)* is not right. How will I check if the switch statement is true?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: a lot of answers and edits, but I still can't really gather what you want to do. What exactly do you want to test? if `$_POST['code']` is set at all? or if one of the `case 'xy':` conditions match?

Comment: http://php.net/in_array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A switch *statement* is *not* an *expression* and thus *cannot* be "true". You can only use a switch *statement* for side-effects, such as assigning a variable.

For instance (fixing the syntax errors)

```
$valid = false; # default to false

switch ($a) {
    case "123":
    case "467":
        $valid = true; # yay, "valid!"
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

if ($valid === true) {
  # ..
}
```

Although, in practice, I would *rarely* write code that looked like that - just *do the action* in the switch or use the if-statement directly; use a function, perhaps containing the switch-statement to write cleaner code.

```
function isValid($secretCode) {
  switch ($secretCode) {
    case "123":
    case "467":
      return true;
    default:
      return false;
  }
}

if (isValid($a)) {
  # ..
}
```

Comment: just wondering where you got the variable `$secretCode` or is that meant to be `$a`?

Comment: @user3057514 $a is the variable outside the function (e.g. `$a = trim($_POST['code'])`), $secretCode is the parameter in the function, and initially has the same value of $a which was supplied as an argument (e.g. `isValid($a)`). I changed the parameter name to make the difference in scopes/variables more apparent, but you could call it something else (including $a).

Comment: thanks very much didnt look at it that way, also in your function i didnt see you `break` any of the cases. how will the switch stop when it find the correct case code? I was taught to always break

Comment: @user3057514 Since `return` will exit the function (and thus switch statement) immediately, there is no reason to also include a `break`.

Comment: @user2864740: As there is no need to break, there is also no need for the `default` case, just end the function with a `return false;`. The other function that you might have been probably looking for is called [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array), it also returns `TRUE`/`FALSE`, valid values can be passed as array.

Comment: @hakre It is my preference/coding style to *return from all switch/if branches* in such a construct, but it could easily be arranged differently as pointed out :) Also, I don't doubt that the OP could possibly use different logic (although I would likely still argue for use a function..), but this answer focuses on the limitations and usage of `switch`.

Comment: @hakre thanks but thats just gonna be alot of `if` statements as I have about `11` cases in my application.

Comment: @user3057514: No, you would have a single if statement, just 11 values inside the array. :)

Comment: @user2864740: Was just saying because in your comment you explained your exiting early instead of break. So I thought, well if you do so (which I think is fine btw), you could also spare the default. That's all.

Answer (score 2):

The `case` keyword ends with a **`:`**(colon) and not with a **`;`** (semicolon)

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I'd guess because, while you're correct that the syntax is incorrect, this doesn't address the whole question as asked.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran look here please  [switch](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) i still doing it with the `;` but thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1):

I'd go in a complete opposite direction and use [`in_array`](http://www.php.net/in_array) instead:

```
//If trim($_POST['code']) is either 123 or 467 then..
if ( in_array( trim( $_POST['code'] ), array("123", "467") ) {
    echo 'Correct!';
} else {
    echo 'Incorrect!';
}
```

Comment: The only real answer!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = trim($_POST['code']);
$hasError = 0;

switch ($a) {
    case "123":
    break;

    case "467":
    break;

    default : 
        $hasError = 1;
    break;
}
```

Comment: why don't you ask OP ? or flame the other answers as they are similar ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$switch_true = true;
switch($a){
    case 123: break; // $switch_true stays true
    case 267: break; // $switch_true stays true
    // for any other value
    default: $switch_true = false; break; // $switch_true becomes false
}
var_dump($switch_true);
```

More about **[`switch` here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)**.

But you should use:

```
$switch_true = in_array($a, array(123, 267));
```

`Switch` is not really meant for this kind of use.

Comment: In your answer, I think it should be  default: $switch_true = false;

Comment: @RaviRokkam **+1.** I haven't waken up yet. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this :

```
    $a = trim($_POST['code']);

    switch ($a) {
    case "123":
        break;
    case "467":
        break;
    default : "incorrect";
    }
```

replace : (colon) with  ; (semicolon).